# What do I use to update apps without an app store?

Tags: application-autoupdate

I'm looking for an automatic Android app updater. I'm manually installing apps that I want using a web browser, and I do not have an app store (Google Play, Mobogenie, Aptoide, etc.) installed. I want to keep them as up to date as possible **without** the hassle of having a full-blown store that offers non-app downloads and porn (even "light porn") right on my device.

If anyone knows a good app-updating app, please leave an answer. Even better, if anyone knows of a clean, unobtrusive app store I can use, show me where I can find that.

*If details are required, I am running Android "Lollipop" 5.1.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S5.*

Comment: I already know of *f-droid* which meets some of my requirements, but it offers so little that it's almost pointless to have installed.

Comment: There are a couple of update watchers (e.g. ChangelogDroid), but they all require the corresponding "app-store apps" being present for the updates themselves. However, there soon will be a possibility to auto-fetch updates via your computer, as soon as Raccoon 4 is released – but that might take a little while.

Comment: @Izzy Yeah but I want an updater *on* my device, not *for* my device with it running on the PC.

Comment: Understood – but that doesn't exist, sorry. Not without the coresponding app-stores installed on your device as well.

Comment: Well, if all the available stores are the ones I can find from [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Operating_Systems/Android/Markets/), then the only way for an updater to get the latest apps is by using various reliable sources.

Comment: I guess you've already checked with our [alternative-markets tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info)?

Answer (score -1):

Google Play and other markets use pull technology to update your applications , without any market you cant update your applications automatically , so i recommend you to install **Google Installer** : http://d-h.st/ztjI

Then install the application and Download all Google Software's listed...

Comment: I actually had a standalone app updater that used AppBrain as its source (I can't seem to find it now, so I don't have a link). However, I had to manually update by clicking each link and going to the website.

Comment: @CyanogenLover I doubt that. AppBrain is just another front-end to Google Play Store, they have no own app repo. True, there's the AppBrain market app – but again, it needs the Playstore app to actually install anything. Long ago, they had the Fast Web Installer to do that; I guess Google didn't like it, so they had to take it down.

Comment: @Izzy Well, I think I was able to use [apk-dl (APK Downloader)](http://apk-dl.com/en) to get the apps. I think it's based in the middle east, because the main site is in Arabic. I'm pretty sure it's legal since they list Google's  price to some of the apps, but I don't try to download apps I'd have to pay for, anyway.